# JS working on index but not my other page I'm editing

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I'm working on an assignment for school.
So, at first my issue was that my JavaScript wasn't working properly on pages, it got fixed now thanks to this kind soul I met through a web developer discord.

My issue now is:
At first the function was working properly across all of my pages, but once I started typing out the code for my menu page and putting in the CSS for it, it completely stopped working just for the menu.html page, but it works for my index.html and all the other pages. I'm afraid that when I started adding on to the other pages that it'll break the javascript function like it did for the menu page. It should work as it does for the others, but I'm unsure why it isn't.

This is the code for my index.html/homepage:
https://jsfiddle.net/senikaura/n8jtz5sq/3/

This is the code for my menu.html/menu page:https://jsfiddle.net/senikaura/Lngd0e24/2/

Both are linked to the same javascript and css files.

INDEX.HTML

```
<html lang="en">
    <head> <!--Header containing title,meta,and links-->
        <title>ctowncuisine</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/qsw5hiv.css"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css"> <!--link reference to CSS stylesheet-->
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav>
        <div class="townlogo">
            <a class="viewmenu" href="index.html"> <!--Technically the header of the page, but used in the body for consistency-->
            <img src="Images/townlogo.jpg" alt="chinese restaurant logo">
        </div>
    </a>
            <ul class="navigation"> <!--section for top navigation bar-->
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="reserve_table.html"><span>Reserve Table</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="burger" id="burger">
                <div class="line1"></div>
                <div class="line2"></div>
                <div class="line3"></div>
                <div class="line4"></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    

     <div class="indexbody"></div>
        <div class="img1"></div> <!--lantern.html image class-->
        <a class="viewmenu" href="menu.html"> <!--Linking border text with href-->
            <div  class="menutext">
            <span class="border ">
            View Our Menu
            </span>
            </div> 
    </a>
        

<section class="section section-mission">
    <h2 class="mission">Our Mission</h2> <!--This is the second heading containing: Our Mission section-->
    <p>To bring quality, style and the wish for good fortune to all of our guests. We provide a high-end experience through Chinese cuisine.
    </p> <!--Paragraph containing the mission statement of TOWN-->
</section>

<div class="img2"> <!--div classifying second image: cookingcropped.html-->
    <span class="border">
    </span>
</div>

<section class="section section-vision">
    <h2 class="vision">Vision</h2> <!--header 2 containing a class for CSS: Vision-->
    <p> <span style="color: rgb( 213 162 141);">TOWN</span> combines a variety of chinese cuisine to excite and delight our customers.
        Our vision for the future is to create experiential dining that is more than just a night out.<br> We aim to bring quality and luxury across all aspects of our brand.
        The approach of <span style="color: rgb( 213 162 141);">TOWN</span> is to develop our brand with the understanding of both our culture and consumer insights.<br> Within our vision always lives the promise of inspiring creativity, conversation and quality.
        Our audience is a high-end clientele who values a dining experience.<br>The age range of our customers are from early 30s-60s. We would like them to come back for both personal dining and events.
    </p>
</section>

<footer>
<div class="rectangle"> <!--This section is the footer-->
    &copy; 2022 ctowncuisine.com designed by <span>MM</span>
</div>
</footer>

<script async defer src="./js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Menu.Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head> <!--Header containing title,meta,and links-->
        <title>ctowncuisine</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/qsw5hiv.css"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
         <!--link reference to CSS stylesheet-->
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav>
        <div class="townlogo">
            <a class="viewmenu" href="index.html"> <!--Technically the header of the page, but used in the body for consistency-->
            <img src="Images/townlogo.jpg" alt="chinese restaurant logo">
        </div>
    </a>

    <div class="topbar"></div>
            <ul class="navigation"> <!--section for top navigation bar-->
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="reserve_table.html"><span>Reserve Table</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="burger" id="burger">
                <div class="line1"></div>
                <div class="line2"></div>
                <div class="line3"></div>
                <div class="line4"></div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="container-wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <img src="Images/charsiu.jpg" alt="egg rolls" class="image">
                <img src="Images/mangostickyrice.jpg" alt="hot pot" class="image">
                <img src="Images/alcoholglasses.jpg" alt="Chinese Barbecue Pork" class="image">
                <img  src="Images/eggrolls.jpg" alt="mango sticky rice dessert" class="image">
                <img src="Images/hotpot.jpg" alt="alcohol beverages" class="image">
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class="appmenu" href="#"> <!--Linking border text with href-->
            <div  class="apptext">
            <span class="appborder ">
            Appetizers
            </span>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </a>

    <a class="soupmenu" href="#"> <!--Linking border text with href-->
        <div  class="souptext">
        <span class="soupborder ">
        Soup & Hot Pot
        </span>
        </div>
    </div> 
</a>

<a class="mainmenu" href="#"> <!--Linking border text with href-->
    <div  class="maintext">
    <span class="mainborder ">
    Main Courses
    </span>
    </div>
</div> 
</a>

<a class="dessmenu" href="#"> <!--Linking border text with href-->
    <div  class="desstext">
    <span class="dessborder ">
    Desserts
    </span>
    </div>
</div> 
</a>

<a class="drinkmenu" href="#"> <!--Linking border text with href-->
    <div  class="drinktext">
    <span class="drinkborder ">
    Beverages
    </span>
    </div>
</div> 
</a>
    
    
    <footer>
        <div class="rectangle"> <!--This section is the footer-->
            &copy; 2022 ctowncuisine.com designed by <span>MM</span>
        </div>
        </footer>

    <script async defer src="./js/app.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

CSS linked to both:

```
/* Index.html styling*/
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.townlogo{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

ul.navigation{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 40%;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: (white);
    font-family: athelas, serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
ul.navigation li{
    list-style: none;
}
ul.navigation a{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.burger{
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div{
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 5px;
}

li a:hover{
    color: rgb(190 30 45);
}

.indexbody{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: athelas, serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    color: rgb(65 57 61);
}

.img1, .img2{
    position: relative;
    opacity:0.70;
    background-position: center;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed; /*Can be adjusted for mobile viewing*/
}


.img1{
    background-image: url('../Images/lantern.jpg');
    min-height: 600px;
}

.img2{
    background-image: url('../Images/cookingcropped.jpg');
    min-height: 400px;
}

.section{
    text-align: center;
    padding:50px 80px;
}

.section-mission{
    background-color: rgb(65 57 61);
    color:white;
}

.section-vision{
    background-color: rgb(65 57 61);
    color:white;
}

.menutext{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black ;
}

.menutext .border{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px;
    padding: 8px;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}

a.viewmenu:link{
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    a.viewmenu:visited{
        text-decoration: none;
        }

a.viewmenu:hover{
background-color: transparent;
}

a.viewmenu:active{
    text-decoration: none;
    }

/*rectangle div contains copyright footer section*/
.rectangle{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: athelas, serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-left: 520px solid rgb(190 30 45) ;
    border-right: 520px solid rgb(190 30 45) ;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.navigation span{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid rgb(190 30 45);
    border-style: outset;
    padding: 5px 12px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* index.html media for javascript and viewing */

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
    .navigation{
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    body{
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .navigation{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 82.5vh;
        top: 17vh;
        background-color: white;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
        z-index:9999
    }
    .navigation li{
        opacity: 100;
    }
    .burger{
        display: block;
    }
    }

    .nav-active{
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }

    .rectangle{
        text-align: center;
        font-family: athelas, serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: 14px;
        border-left: 200px solid rgb(190 30 45) ;
        border-right: 200px solid rgb(190 30 45) ;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

/* Menu.html CSS styling*/

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 1rem;
    align-items: center;
}

.image {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    object-fit: cover;
    opacity: 65%;
}

.container-wrapper {
    max-width: 1500px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}

.apptext .appborder{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 36%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px;
    padding: 12px;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
    font-family: athelas, serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black ;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}

.apptext .appborder:hover{
    color: rgb(215 228 194);
}

a.appmenu:link{
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    a.app:visited{
        text-decoration: none;
        }

a.appmenu:hover{
    color: transparent;
}

a.appmenu:active{
    text-decoration: none;
    }

.souptext .soupborder{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 64.5%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px;
    padding: 12px;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
    font-family: athelas, serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black ;
    text-decoration: none;
        
    }
    
.souptext .soupborder:hover{
    color: rgb(215 228 194);
    }
    
a.soupmenu:link{
    text-decoration: none;
    }
    
a.soupmenu:visited{
        text-decoration: none;
        }
    
a.soupmenu:hover{
    color: transparent;
    }
    
a.soupmenu:active{
        text-decoration: none;
        }

.maintext .mainborder{
    position: absolute;
    top: 92%;
    left: 21%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px;
    padding: 12px;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
    font-family: athelas, serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black ;
    text-decoration: none;
        
    }
    
.maintext .mainborder:hover{
    color: rgb(215 228 194);
    }
    
a.mainmenu:link{
    text-decoration: none;
    }
    
a.mainmenu:visited{
        text-decoration: none;
        }
    
a.mainmenu:hover{
    color: transparent;
    }
    
a.mainmenu:active{
        text-decoration: none;
        }

.desstext .dessborder{
    position: absolute;
    top: 92%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px;
    padding: 12px;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
    font-family: athelas, serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black ;
    text-decoration: none;
        
    }
    
.desstext .dessborder:hover{
    color: rgb(215 228 194);
    }
    
a.dessmenu:link{
    text-decoration: none;
    }
    
a.dessmenu:visited{
        text-decoration: none;
        }
    
a.dessmenu:hover{
    color: transparent;
    }
    
a.dessmenu:active{
        text-decoration: none;
        }

.drinktext .drinkborder{
    position: absolute;
    top: 92%;
    left: 79%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px;
    padding: 12px;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
    font-family: athelas, serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black ;
    text-decoration: none;
        
    }
    
.drinktext .drinkborder:hover{
    color: rgb(215 228 194);
    }
    
a.drinkmenu:link{
    text-decoration: none;
    }
    
a.drinkmenu:visited{
        text-decoration: none;
        }
    
a.drinkmenu:hover{
    color: transparent;
    }
    
a.drinkmenu:active{
        text-decoration: none;
        }
```

Javascript linked to both:

```
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
const nav = document.querySelector('.navigation');

const navSlide = () => {


  nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

 
}

burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
   navSlide();
})
```

[image: File Structure]

Comment: You need to check if the elements are on the page first, ex: if on one page there is no burger element the code will fail

Comment: why are you using async and defer together on the script tag?? Maybe this is the main cause of your problem. Learn more about [async and defer](https://pagespeedchecklist.com/async-and-defer)

Comment: Just plain defer should suffice.

Comment: @Lk77 There is a burger across all the pages.

Comment: @KunalTanwar Someone helped me with the coding and told me to try that. It made it work though, so I thought it was fine

Comment: You should use either one of them

Comment: @KunalTanwar so is it best that I just go with only one of them?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the path of the js file. maybe the menu is on another folder or something

Comment: in your case you should use defer!

Comment: You didn't mention what is not working `css` or `js`??

Comment: Sorry, what isn't working is my .burger in CSS along with the @media that helps with the transitions and such. Which is used for the navSlide function in Js. So, I can have a responsive navigation bar. 

The index.html page it works perfectly fine and I can click on it, once I get to the menu.html page it won't click, hover or appear after I put some images on the page and did some CSS to the menu.html page.

Comment: @AtifKhan The menu.html file is all in the same section as the rest of the pages

Comment: @KunalTanwar It wouldn't let me tag you in the above comment where i explain what's not working ^^

Comment: can you post an image of your folder structure?

Comment: @KunalTanwar Posted it!

Comment: use `./CSS/style.css`

Comment: If you use your browser dev tools and right click -> inspect the burger menu button - then in your second example, you will _not_ land on the button, but on the `.container-wrapper` element. This is positioned _on top_ of the button, therefor your clicks that you think are "on" the button, never actually reach it.

Comment: @KunalTanwar tried that, didn't work still

Comment: @CBroe so all I need to do is move the container wrappers below my .burger through CSS or HTML? I know in CSS it is above the container wrapper, but have to check the HTML. I'm a bit confused

Comment: I can't tell what exactly is causing the z-axis issue right now; but if you add `position: relative` for `nav`, that appears to fix it.